# Does Expectation Algebra Assume Normal Distribution?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I am using expectation algebra to derive a Kalman Filter for a signal processing application. Data are student-T distributed. I took a course on random variables when I was in grad school $> 15$ years ago, but I'm an EE (not a mathematician) so I'm quite rusty on this subject. Here is my question:

1.) Is expectation algebra predicated on a Gaussian distribution? For instance, are rules such as $V(k * x) = k^2 * V(x)$ valid for normal distributions but not others?

2.) If the answer to $1)$ is yes, has anyone developed a similar body of rules for non-Gaussian distributed data? I am particularly interested in rules that hold $\text{student-}T, \nu > 1$.

In case it matters, the student distribution has $\nu\geq  3$, but not so large that it starts to look like infinity. (In other words, not so large that distribution starts to look Guassian.)

Comment: $V(k X) = k^2 \, V(X)$ is true in general for the variance if it exists.  Similarly  $\mathbb E[k X] = k  \,\mathbb E[X]$ for the expectation

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what the rules of "expectation algebra" are, and this is nonstandard term, so I'm not sure what you mean.

With that said, the Wikipedia article [Algebra of random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Algebra_of_random_variables&oldid=1055049586) has a section entitled "Expectation algebra of random variables."  Perhaps those rules are what you mean?

If so, then the rules are *not* predicated on Gaussianness.  Exactly why they hold depends on your axiomatization of probability theory: if you think probabilities are fundamental, then they are provable consequences of the definition of expectation; if you think expectations are fundamental, then they are provable consequences of the expectation axioms.

For example: $$\mathbb{E}[X+Y]=\mathbb{E}[X]+\mathbb{E}[Y]$$ follows from…

Probabilities

First, recall the definition of $X+Y$ as a pointwise sum: for any "world index" $\omega\in\Omega$, $$(X+Y)(\omega)=X(\omega)+Y(\omega)$$

Second, recall the definition of expectation as Lebesgue integral: $$\mathbb{E}[Z]=\int_{\Omega}{Z(\omega)\,\mathbb{P}(d\omega)}$$

Thus \begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X+Y]&=\int_{\Omega}{X(\omega)+Y(\omega)\,\mathbb{P}(d\omega)} \\
&=\int_{\Omega}{X(\omega)\,\mathbb{P}(d\omega)}+\int_{\Omega}{Y(\omega)\,\mathbb{P}(d\omega)} \\
&=\mathbb{E}[X]+\mathbb{E}[Y]
\end{align*} by the linearity of the integral.

Expectations

The claim is an axiom defining expectation.  (In the linked Wikipedia article above, it is axiom #3 under "Algebra of complex random variables".)